# Connection issue of Xib and created outlets

Tags: iphone, connection, xib

I have two seprate projects and both having viewController classes  with same name .
I import one projects file in other with Xib,i changed second class with its xib name and its running fine .
But when i look in xib the objects in xib  not showing its refrence outlets which i created  in .h class. please help me in this situation .

Comment: You dont you hook them up manually?

Comment: i am not gettin your ponit please elaborate

Comment: Sorry typo and auto-correct converted why to you.  Why don't you hook them up manually.

Comment: i have done beforte throgh xib, will it be not possible again to hook it up throug xib

Answer (score 1):

click the File's owner in which xib you wants to referenced and do select or write the class name for appropriate class

- select File's owner
- click identity inspector(3rd tab on inspector view)
- select or write appropriate class names under custom class.

After this, the reference which you add on .h file will show on it.

Comment: i try this, but when i click editor to open side by side xib and its interface , it showing second view controoler class not the changed name its own class . i changed name in filename of xib in inspector .

Comment: Have you to tried to write appropriate view controller name on file name under file inspector(first tab)?